# How to print only blue characters in textview

Tags: python, gtk

I want to get the characters printed only in blue.
How to do it?

Here is the sample program code, which is a fragment of most of the program.

I would be very grateful for your help.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class TextViewWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="awesome gui")
        self.set_resizable(True)
        self.set_default_size(700, 550)
        self.grid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(self.grid)
        self.create_textview()
        self.buffer = []

    def create_textview(self):
        scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        scrolledwindow.set_hexpand(True)
        scrolledwindow.set_vexpand(True)
        self.grid.attach(scrolledwindow, 0, 2, 80, 1)
        self.textview = Gtk.TextView()
        scrolledwindow.add(self.textview)

        self.textbuffer = self.textview.get_buffer()
        self.textview.set_editable(False)
        self.textview.set_cursor_visible(False)

        self.textview.connect("key-press-event", self.on_key_down)

    def on_key_down(self, widget, event, data=None):

        znak_p = event.string

        end_iter_m = self.textbuffer.get_iter_at_line_offset(1, 1)
        qwerty_tag = self.textbuffer.create_tag(None, editable=True, foreground="blue")
        self.textbuffer.insert_with_tags(end_iter_m, znak_p, qwerty_tag)

win = TextViewWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `on_key_down` handler is wrong:

- you are creating an anonymous tag every time you're pressing a key
- you are using an invalid string for the [`GtkTextTag:foreground`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextTag.html#GtkTextTag--foreground) property
- you are not returning a value from the callback telling GTK whether you handled the event (and thus should stop the event propagation) or not.

The `GtkTextTag:foreground` property uses the same format as the [`gdk_rgba_parse()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-RGBA-Colors.html#gdk-rgba-parse) function; if you want a blue color, you should use `rgba(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)` instead of "blue".

A correct handler is:

```py
    def on_key_down(self, widget, event, data=None):
        znak_p = event.string
        end_iter_m = self.textbuffer.get
        self.textbuffer.insert_with_tags(end_iter_m, znak_p, self.qwerty_tag)
        return True
```